# yum install trying other mirror - остановить процесс

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, putty, yum

Будучи неопытным пользователем linux-систем, столкнулся с проблемой: через PuTTY подключился к удалённому серверу и пытался обновить пакет php-fpm, ввёл команду `sudo yum install php-fpm` и yum начал перебирать зеркала с пакетами, выдавая ошибки вида:

> "Failed to connect to 2a00:1f00:dc06:10::106: Network is unreachable"
>   Trying other mirror.

Очевидно, была проблема с доступностью сети. Однако, попытавшись остановить процесс через сочетание клавиш `Ctrl + C`, я понял, что это не работает, остановить повторяющиеся попытки менеджера yum найти зеркало мне никак не удавалось. Страх и ужас, неизбывная паника охватили мой разум. "Ведь это сервер организации! А вдруг я что-нибудь сломаю? А что если..." - эти вопросы непрестанно звучали в моей голове. И что же мне было делать?

Comment: `ping ya.ru` ; `ping 8.8.8.8` чё выдают?

Answer (score 1):

> остановить повторяющиеся попытки менеджера yum

Если Вы  не предпринимали каких-то нестандартных действий, то закрытие терминала, на которым Вы работаете, автоматически приводит к закрытию **всех** процессов, запущенных с этого терминала. Не буду касаться фоновых - там несколько сложнее...

Comment: Кроме фоновых бывают остановленные.

Comment: @0anriy Насколько я помню, бывает 8 типов состояния процесса. Но прибиваются они не по типу состояния, а по ppid и sid.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы остановить процесс, вместо сочетания `Ctrl + C` нужно использовать `Ctrl + Z`

Comment: *Остановить* и *прервать* — два разных сигнала процессу с разным, как правило, откликом. Во втором случае процесс в памяти, и продолжает блокировать через файлы блокировки запуск нового экземпляра (это касается *yum* и некоторых других программ). Также при попытке корректного выхода из терминала (завершения сессии), это невозможно будет осуществить из-за остановленных процессов.

Comment: @0andriy, вы правы, спасибо. В дальнейшем я узнал, что завершить процесс можно командой kill, например, kill -TERM <номер процесса>, то есть, "убить процесс". Вот тут хорошая статья с рекомендациями https://habr.com/post/95102/

Можете дополнить и опубликовать полный ответ, приму его в качестве основного.

Comment: *Убить* процесс — это ещё один вид сигнала. Команда *kill*, несмотря на название, является способом **послать сигнал** процессу. А ответы мне лень писать.